# Unable to submit transaction using foundry's cast send command | Must be authenticated

Tags: chainlink, foundry

I'm unable to submit transaction to a Chainlink VRFv2Coordinator powered contract using `cast send`.
Hitting the error -

```
(code: -32000, message: Must be authenticated!, data: None)
```

Command

```
cast send 0xee8e59DBc30fA2B23B64CEE4dC9ca02a1415B363 --private-key <private-key> "requestRandomWords()" --rpc-url https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/<API-KEY>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What address are you calling from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Summary - this specific error

For this specific issue, it's related to permissions of your RPC_URL. You'll need to fix it, update it, or use a different one. `Must be authenticated` is an error code coming from the rpc and not the smart contract.

## Summary - more information than you thought

However, you'll need to redeploy this contract with a subId that you own.

### More information

Even if you *did* get past this, you'd still run into either:

```
MustBeSubOwner
```

Or a generic revert, always!

The `s_subscriptionId` you're using is `3960`, which is owned by address `0x8fa510072009e71cfd447169ab5a84cac394f58a`. So you'd need to call the `requestRandomWords` with that address.

However, your contract is owned by `0xE72a5579B8dF4bC9F4EF42F8619427AE1Fe6759F`, so it needs to be called by your address. This is impossible to call a function from two addresses, so this function will always revert!

#### Way too much information

##### How did I find the subscription Id?

Since your subscription Id was an `immutable` variable, that means it's stored in the byte code of the contract and not storage. You can look at the end of the [original contract creation](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x294f16a4be32100be0fc632ab65e78e949acb277dd652a30e6f022fe684e1cd4) to see the contract creation transaction. At the end of the call data is where constructor arguments are usually stored. You'll be able to easily see all the normal stuff like the keyhash `79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15` and link token address `326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06F`, as well as this innocuous little `f78` right near the end, if we pop that into cast:

```
cast --to-base f78 dec
```

We get `3960`.

We could look at the owner of that subId on the contract, or just jump over to the [vrf.chain.link](https://vrf.chain.link/goerli/3960) site for that subId.

Comment: Excellent response, yes I created the sub and contract with different addresses. I didnt even know thats not possible :raised_hands:. Next, regarding immutable variable I had no idea that we can retrieve using bytecode :raised_hands:

Fixed the RPC url issue as well. Thank You